# XTemplate Same level of array in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Given two (or more) arrays of the same length, how do you express the values and desired output format within an ExtJS XTemplate?  For example, my input data looks similar to:

```
var data = {
    name        : 'xxx',
    rowTitleArr : ['1','2','3'],
    colTitleArr : ['a','b','c']
};
```

... and I'd like the output in the form:

> 1 a 
>   2 b 
>   3 c

Answer (score 0):

You could map the input data to a more manageable scope using a utility function in the template:

```js
{
    // component config ...

    data: data,
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for="this.merge(values.rowTitleArr, values.colTitleArr)">',
            '{row} {col} <br/>',
        '</tpl>',
        {
            merge: function(a1, a2){
                var len = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length);
                    for(var i=0, arr=[]; i<len; i++)
                        arr.push({ row: a1[i], col: a2[i] });
                return arr;
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[**» fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7ne)